# SignalR Client using Python

Tags: python, .net, signalr, server-sent-events, signalr-hub

I'm trying to develop a SignalR client using Python. While I've explored libraries like [signalr](https://pypi.org/project/signalr-client/) and [signalrcore](https://pypi.org/project/signalrcore/), my SignalR Hub server developed on an older version (.Net Framework 4.8), making it challenging to utilize these libraries. Additionally, my server employs the Server-Sent Events (SSE) transport type for data transmission which these libraries doesn't support.

I've managed to successfully retrieve data in my .Net code where after establishing the connection, I need to invoke an API endpoint by providing the connectionId obtained through the negotiation process with the hub. This action is intended to trigger the event flow to the SignalR client. Now striving to replicate this functionality in Python.

However, I'm encountering a roadblock as the API invocation is resulting in an "invalid connectionId" error.

Here are the sequential steps I'm following in Python:

1. Initiate negotiation to obtain connection details such as connectionToken, connectionId, and other metadata.

   Request: `GET https://myhuburl:443/ws/signalr/negotiate`

   Response:

   ```
   {
        "url": "/ws/signalr/",
        "connectionToken": "xxxx",
        "connectionId": "asdf..."
        ....
   }
   ```
2. Employ the connectionToken to establish a connection with the SignalR Hub.

   Request: `GET https://myhuburl:443/ws/signalr/connect?connectionData=[{"Name":"HubName"}]&connectionToken=xxxxxxxxx`

   Response: Connects to SSE and starts receiving empty (`{}`) messages.
3. Attempt to trigger an event using the connectionId via an API call.

   Request: `GET https://myhuburl:8080/api/sr/eventssubscription/{connectionId}`

   Response: `{"error":"Invalid connectionId"} // This return success when I'm using the connectionId which I get from .Net Client console.`

Expecting help from anyone who has knowledge of SignalR. (or DesigoCC)